# Problem with #available for UIPopoverPresentationController sourceItem with Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst

Using Xcode 14.0.1 I'm working on an iOS/iPadOS app with an iOS deployment target of iOS 15.0. I am setting up a view controller to be shown as a popover. To support the iPad I set the `barButtonItem` of the controller's `popoverPresentationController`. I also wanted to use the new `sourceItem` property added in iOS 16.0. This leaves me with code as follows:

```
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
nc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    nc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceItem = btnAdd
} else {
    nc.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = btnAdd
}
```

This all works just fine when building and running for iOS/iPadOS.

I also want to make my app for macOS using Mac Catalyst. So I added the Mac Catalyst supported destination to my target (and removed the non-Catalyst Mac option). When I try to build the target against my Mac (running macOS 12.6), I get an error on the `sourceItem` line:

```
nc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceItem = btnAdd
```

The error states:

> Value of type 'UIPopoverPresenationController' has no member 'sourceItem'

Sure enough, the documentation shows `sourceItem` as only being available for iOS 16.0+ and no others such as a Mac Catalyst version.

I've attempted to modify the `#available` line. I've tried things such as:

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, macOS 13.0, *) {
```

and

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, macCatalyst 16.0, *) {
```

but none of those attempts solve the error.

What change is needed to this code so it will compile under iOS 15, 16, and Mac Catalyst (macOS 12.3 and later)? The change would seem to require using the `barButtomItem` line under Mac Catalyst and iOS 15 and only use the `sourceItem` line for iOS 16.0+.

Of course I could simply remove the use of `sourceItem` and just have the one line:

```
nc.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = btnAdd
```

but `barButtonItem` was deprecated as of iOS 16.0 in favor of `sourceItem` so I'd like to try to use it (yes, I know `barButtomItem` will continue to work but that's not the point of this question).

It seems like a bug that `sourceItem` is not available for Mac Catalyst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved with the release of Xcode 14.1.

When looking at the documentation for `UIPopoverPresenationController sourceItem` in Xcode 14.0.1 it was marked as only being available for iOS 16.0+ and nothing else.

Now with Xcode 14.1 the documentation shows it as available for iOS 16.0+ and Mac Catalyst 16.0+ and the code in my question now compiles just fine.

So it seems this was a bug in the header files failing to mark it for Mac Catalyst and that bug has been resolved.